# Jquery Mobile app works on web browser but when I build it on phonegap for android, css not shown

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

Jquery Mobile app works on web browser but when I build it on phonegap for android, css not shown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Insert Page Title Here</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Insert Content Here</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

**This is simple w3.com code css not working when I make it android app with build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: are you referring the CSS and scripts using the code.jquery.com url ? The CSS and JavaScript should be local to ur project

Comment: I saw apps referring code.jquery.com is it a problem ?

Comment: Better to have local versions. What if your user has no data connection when they load up?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to state what version of PhoneGap and android you are using.
If you are on PhoneGap 4, you will need to white-list your remote domains (e.g. http://code.jquery.com).

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for documentation on how to use the whitelisting plugin.

Comment: what I build on phonegap.com is only a html file which I wrote its all content, so I need to add a config.xml file too ?

Comment: Yes, you should have a configuration file. Check the Phone Gap documentation.

Answer (score 0):

when you build it on phonegap for android. if network is not stable or not available. jQuery mobile CSS doens't work. it seems use jQuery mobile CDN

make sure network is ok first

Comment: changed all references to CDN s still it doesnt work

Comment: Best practice is to load assets from mobile device, NOT network. You also need to wait for the `deviceready` event. SEE: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)